# Issue in de-serializing JSON String with mapper

Tags: java, json-deserialization, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I am trying to deserialize the below JSON string:

```
 {"id" : "1234",
  "name" : "Name",
  "description" : "abcd\n\rdghsdghjdg",
  "risk" : "LOW",
  "status" : "Open",
  "autoGenerated" : false,
  "comments" : "",
  "category" : [ "abc", "def" ],
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2021-11-19T11:23:04.948074Z",
  "lastModifiedBy" : "amallik",
  "readableId" : "2553",
  "componentBlocks" : [ ],
  "threatTemplateId" : "5678",
  "threatTags" : [ ],
  "threatComponents" : [ ],
  "components" : {
    "blocks" : [ ],
    "lines" : [ ],
    "connections" : [ ]
  },
  "mitigationList" : [ {
    "mitigationTemplateId" : "155",
    "title" : "abcd",
  }, {
    "mitigationTemplateId" : "152",
    "title" : "efgh",
  }, {
    "mitigationTemplateId" : "153",
    "title" : "ijkl",
  }],
  "rejected" : false,
  "edited" : true
}
```

with the following statement:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(currentPayload, new TypeReference<Map<String, LinkedHashMap>>(){});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot coerce empty String ("") to element of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` (but could if coercion was enabled using `CoercionConfig`)
 at [Source: (String)"{
[truncated chars]; line: 8, column: 16] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["comments"])
```

Could anyone please help here regarding fixing this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I would highly recommend creating a Pojo to read the value into that instead of a trying to squeeze it into a `Map<String, LinkedHashMap>`

Comment: @magicmn I cannot use a concrete pojo here as json string might be a serialization of different objects. So on concrete pojo would not be enough here.